# Updating dates in a data frame based on user input

Tags: r

I have an input variable for a data set in R that assesses a list of tools. It looks as follows:

```
type <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a Barcode: "))
```

I have two columns, one that contains the information found with the input statement (a set of barcode numbers), and one that contains a date that a certain thing was entered into the 'tool' variable. I understand how to use function Sys.Date and it works fine for me, I am just having a hard time getting it to update the column in the data frame when something is input rather than outputting the current date in the console. Ideal output for this would be just an update to the data frame column, in the row that the barcode input is. For example, ideal output would look like the following:

```
Barcode_Number, Date_Used
5698, 2018-07-07
4570, 2018-07-11
4567, 2018-07-12
3298, 2018-07-13
```

The structure of the barcode number is just a 4 digit number input into tool type. That Barcode number input is then assessed for the date of its input, and the date is updated in the Date_Used column. The data frame being updated is only two rows, just the Barcode row and the date row. Once a barcode is input into the type variable statement, ideally I want the date of the input to update in the date row for the specific tool. 
Thank you!

Comment: You could read the inputted date with as.Date() or as.POSIXct() or as.POSIClt().

Comment: How would you suggest I try this? I am having trouble with updating the specific row rather than all of the rows, and I am not sure how to actually take the date of an input

Comment: Greg, could you show us the structure/content of the input captured by the barcode reader? That would help us help you parsing it. We might also need an example of the structure of the dataframe you are trying to update.